# CORS not working in Angular 11 and Asp.net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, cors, angular11

I'm experiencing some difficulties with CORS in angular 11 and Asp.net Core 2.1.1. The Angular server running on port 4201, the Asp.net Core server on port 8990. I always get an error like this

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.31.80.108:8990/api/localization/login' from origin 'http://10.31.80.108:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

although I have enabled CORS in the Startup.cs file:

```
 app.UseCors(builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                                      .AllowAnyHeader()                                           
                                      .WithOrigins(new []{ "http://10.31.80.108", "http://10.31.80.108:4201"})
                                      //.WithOrigins(origins.ToArray())
                                      .AllowCredentials());
```

I've tried different variations that should allow all requests, but it doesn't work in Angular. Can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Here is most of the Startup file:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {                
           ...
        });

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddMemoryCache();
    //  services.AddCors();
        services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin", builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader()
                   .AllowCredentials();
        })); }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Configuration["CultureOptions:DefaultCulture"]);
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(Configuration["CultureOptions:DefaultCulture"]);

        var cultureOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(new CultureInfo(Configuration["CultureOptions:DefaultCulture"])),
        };
        var configCultures = Configuration.GetSection("CultureOptions:SupportedCultures").GetChildren();
        configCultures.ForEach(config =>
        {
            cultureOptions.SupportedCultures.Add(new CultureInfo(config.Value));
            cultureOptions.SupportedUICultures.Add(new CultureInfo(config.Value));
        });
        app.UseRequestLocalization(cultureOptions);

        List<string> origins = Configuration.GetSection("Origins:value").Get<List<string>>();
        app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");

 if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // https://joonasw.net/view/hsts-in-aspnet-core
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();            

      

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a wrong syntax. try this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));
            
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            .....

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            //app.UseAuthorization();
         }
```

if it works replace AllowAnyOrigin() with yours

```
 .WithOrigins ("http://10.31.80.108", "http://10.31.80.108:4201");
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error, even with AllowAnoOrigin().

Comment: Can you post your whole startup pls, better with  the update  i offered?

Comment: I added most of the Startup Code

Comment: Thank you. Can you please add all configure section.

Comment: I've added the whole configure method

Comment: Pls try to move  services.AddCors to the top of ConfigureServices. And why I can't see   app.UseCors ?